# Entity Framework asp net core relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models:
User:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EDiary.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Podaj imię")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Imię jest zbyt długie. Max. 25 znaków.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Podaj nazwisko")]
        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Nazwisko jest zbyt długie. Max. 25 znaków.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Podaj prawidłowy adres e-mail")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Hasło musi składać się z conajmniej 7 znaków")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Class Class { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EDiary.Models
{
    public class Class
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public User Educator { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I do add-migration I get an error: Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Class.Educator' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ClassId to User:

```
public class User
    {
        .....
  public int? ClassId {get; set;}
     [ForeignKey(nameof(ClassId))]
        [InverseProperty("Users")]
        public Class Class { get; set; }
    }
```

and  EducatorId  to Class

```
   public class Class
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
       public string ClassName { get; set; }

         [ForeignKey("Educator")]
       public int? EducatorId {get; set;}
       public User Educator { get; set; }
      
          [InverseProperty("Class")]
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Try this. public int? ClassId {get; set;} What error do you have?

Comment: Did you remove    public User Educator { get; set; } from Class?

Comment: No, because educator is educator, I need ClassId to define a student's class.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the answer.

Comment: I got rid of ICollection <User> Users, added public int ClassId {get; set;} and it works. Thanks!